# Eigen: efficient ways to repeatedly operate on sub-matrices

Tags: c++, eigen3

In an algorithm that I want to implement, I need to repeatedly operate on a matrix that is formed by a set of rows taken from another existing matrix. For clarity, I will call "`A`" the original matrix, and "`B`" the "working matrix" (consisting in some rows of `A`).

The algorithm proceeds as follows:

1. Select a row `r` from `A`
2. Either insert or remove such row in `B`
3. Perform some operations with `B` (if it is not empty)
4. Repeat

Some relevant information:

- If `r` has to be inserted in `B`, I am sure that it is not already there (no risk of creating duplicates)
- If `r` has to be removed from `B`, I am sure that it is already there (no risk to remove non-existent rows)
- The ordering of the rows inside `B` does not matter

My objective is to implement this part of the algorithm efficiently using Eigen. With efficiently, I mainly refer to execution time.

I came up with 3 different solutions, I would like to know what are your thoughts about them and what improvements could be added.

## Solution 1: resize and copy

The idea is to store `B` in a `MatrixXd` instance that is repeatedly expanded/contracted. Since ordering of the rows does not matter, I stack new rows at the bottom of `B`. When I need to remove a row from `B`, I simply copy lower rows upwards.

```cpp
class Algorithm1 {
public:
  bool show_b;

  Algorithm1(const Eigen::MatrixXd& M) : A(M), B(0,M.cols()), show_b(false) {
    rows.reserve(A.rows());
  }

  void run(const std::vector<std::pair<bool,int>>& ops) {
    for(const auto& op : ops) {
      if(rows.size() > 0) {
        // If B is not empty, do something with it (print is just an example)
        if(show_b)
          std::cout << "-------------------" << std::endl << "B is:" << std::endl << B << std::endl;
      }

      // check if we have to insert or remove the row
      if(op.first) {
        // Row 'op.second' should be added to B.
        B.conservativeResize(rows.size()+1, A.cols()); // add space for a column at the bottom
        B.row(rows.size()) = A.row(op.second); // copy the desired row from A to B
        rows.push_back(op.second); // keep track of which rows are inside B
      }
      else {
        // Row 'op.second' should be removed from B.
        auto it = std::find(rows.begin(), rows.end(), op.second); // find where the row is stored in B
        int r = std::distance(rows.begin(), it); // get the actual index
        for(int i=r; i<rows.size()-1; i++)
          B.row(i) = B.row(i+1); // copy each row to the one above
        B.conservativeResize(rows.size()-1, A.cols()); // remove the last row of B
        rows.erase(it); // remove the row also from this list
      }
    }
  }

private:
  Eigen::MatrixXd A; // Original matrix
  Eigen::MatrixXd B; // Working matrix
  std::vector<int> rows; // list of rows in B, such that A.row(rows[i]) equals B.row(i)
};
```

Note that in principle the rows to be added/removed are selected internally by the algorithm. However, to keep it simpler, I manually pass a "list of operations" as a parameter to the algorithm. Each element of the `std::vector` is a `pair` whose first element tells if the row has to be added (`pair.first` is `true`) or removed (`pair.first` is `false`). The index of the row to be selected is given in `pair.second` (the index refers to the rows of `A`).

## Solution 2: `Eigen::Map`

Another solution that I could think of is to store the data of `B` in a "raw buffer", which can be used in the main algorithm via a `Eigen::Map`. To be able to quickly add/remove an entire row
from the buffer, I had to use row-major ordering for both `A` and `B`.

```cpp
class Algorithm2 {
public:
  // Row-major matrix
  typedef Eigen::Matrix<double,Eigen::Dynamic,Eigen::Dynamic,Eigen::RowMajor> RMatrixXd;

  bool show_b;

  Algorithm2(const Eigen::MatrixXd& M) : A(M), show_b(false) {
    rows.reserve(A.rows());
    data.reserve(A.size());
  }

  void run(const std::vector<std::pair<bool,int>>& ops) {
    for(const auto& op : ops) {
      if(rows.size() > 0) {
        // Create the sub-matrix B using a Map
        Eigen::Map<RMatrixXd> B(data.data(), rows.size(), A.cols());

        // Do something with it (print is just an example)
        if(show_b)
          std::cout << "-------------------" << std::endl << "B is:" << std::endl << B << std::endl;
      }

      // check if we have to insert or remove the row
      if(op.first) {
        // Row 'op.second' should be added to B.
        // append the row content inside the data
        data.insert(
          data.end(), // append at the end
          A.data() + op.second*A.cols(), // from the beginning of the row
          A.data() + (op.second+1)*A.cols() // until the beginning of the next one
        );
        rows.push_back(op.second); // keep track of which rows are inside B
      }
      else {
        // Row 'op.second' should be removed from B.
        auto it = std::find(rows.begin(), rows.end(), op.second); // find where the row is stored in B
        int r = std::distance(rows.begin(), it); // get the actual index
        data.erase(data.begin()+r*A.cols(), data.begin()+(r+1)*A.cols()); // remove the corresponding values from the data
        rows.erase(it); // remove the row also from this list
      }
    }
  }

private:
  RMatrixXd A; // The original matrix
  std::vector<int> rows; // list of rows in B, such that A.row(rows[i]) equals B.row(i)
  std::vector<double> data; // content of B (row-major ordering)
};
```

## Solution 3: new overload of `operator()`

Using the latest version of Eigen, it is possible to select a sub-matrix directly via `operator()`. In practice, the matrix `B` can be obtained as `A( rows-to-select , Eigen::all )`.

```cpp
class Algorithm3 {
public:
  bool show_b;

  Algorithm3(const Eigen::MatrixXd& M) : A(M), show_b(false) {
    rows.reserve(A.rows());
  }

  void run(const std::vector<std::pair<bool,int>>& ops) {
    for(const auto& op : ops) {
      if(rows.size() > 0) {
        // Create the sub-matrix B
        auto B = A(rows, Eigen::all);

        // Do something with it (print is just an example)
        if(show_b)
          std::cout << "-------------------" << std::endl << "B is:" << std::endl << B << std::endl;
      }

      // check if we have to insert or remove the row
      if(op.first) {
        // Row 'op.second' should be added to B.
        rows.push_back(op.second); // keep track of which rows are inside B
      }
      else {
        // Row 'op.second' should be removed from B.
        rows.erase(std::find(rows.begin(), rows.end(), op.second)); // remove the row from the list
      }
    }
  }

private:
  Eigen::MatrixXd A; // The original matrix
  std::vector<int> rows; // list of rows in B, such that A.row(rows[i]) equals B.row(i)
};
```

## Quick comparison of the solutions

In the following there is a simple program to record execution times:

```cpp
int main() {

  Eigen::MatrixXd A(3,3);
  A << 0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,2;

  std::vector<std::pair<bool,int>> ops {
    // {add=true/remove=false, row-index} // which rows will now be inside B
    {true, 1}, // 1
    {true, 0}, // 0 1
    {true, 2}, // 0 1 2
    {false,0}, // 1 2
    {false,2}, // 1
    {true, 2}, // 1 2
    {false,1}, // 2
    {true, 0}, // 0 2
    {true, 1}, // 0 1 2
    {false,0}, // 1 2
    {false,1}, // 2
    {false,2}, // empty
  };

  // Instanciate
  Algorithm1 alg1(A);
  Algorithm2 alg2(A);
  Algorithm3 alg3(A);

  // warm-up
  for(int i=0; i<1000; i++) {
    alg1.run(ops);
    alg2.run(ops);
    alg3.run(ops);
  }

  // run the 3 algorithms
  auto start1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
  for(int i=0; i<1000; i++)
    alg1.run(ops);
  auto end1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

  auto start2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
  for(int i=0; i<1000; i++)
    alg2.run(ops);
  auto end2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

  auto start3 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
  for(int i=0; i<1000; i++)
    alg3.run(ops);
  auto end3 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

  // show the results
  std::cout << "Alg1 took " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(end1-start1).count() << "ns" << std::endl;
  std::cout << "Alg2 took " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(end2-start2).count() << "ns" << std::endl;
  std::cout << "Alg3 took " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(end3-start3).count() << "ns" << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

On my laptop, the best results are given by the 2nd strategy, followed by the 3rd one (~3.4 times longer) and the 1st one (~4.3 times slower).

What do you think? Do the results make sense compared to your experience? Can you suggest any better strategy?